# fn.call(this) versus fn() when defining a CommonJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

It's common to see CommonJS modules defined using the following idiom:

```
(function() {
   var logThis = function() { console.log(this); }
   module.exports = logThis;
}).call(this);
```

[Underscore.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js), for example, does this.

I just spend half an hour discussing with a colleague why they invoke the closure with `call(this)`. This will cause the value of `this` inside the closure to be inherited from the caller, rather than being set to the global object. However, when I tested this in Node.js, the value of `this` inside the module was always the global object, even when I loaded and ran it like this:

```
var bar = {};
bar.foo = function() { var foo = require("./foo"); foo(); }
```

I was really expecting to see the `bar` object in the console, but actually I see the global object. It then occurred to me that this might be because modules like Underscore.js are also used in a web context. But in that case it would be loaded with a <script> tag so `this` will always be equal to the global object anyway.

What gives? I'm sure there is a reason for using this construct but I can't see the practical difference in this particular case whether the module is being used in Node.js or in a webpage.

**Update:** Just to clarify, I can think of a number of cases where this *could* make a difference. For example, if I say:

```
var bar = {}
var foo = require("./foo");
bar.foo = foo;
bar.foo();
```

(Thanks to @Pointy for correcting my original example.)

I would expect the closure in the module to be evaluated when `require()` is called, which means that the value of `this` inside it would be bound to the global object, which would be written to the console even though `foo()` is then invoked as a member of the "bar" object. However, I am seeing the "bar" object in the console even in this example. I guess that `this` is not being bound to the closure as I expected?

In a nutshell, I'm looking for one example where a module like Underscore.js will have different behavior due to being wrapped in a closure invoked with `fn.call(this)` instead of just `fn()`, either in Node.js or in a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to "foo" inside "bar.foo" is made without any context, so the global context is used.  The fact that it's inside a function where `this` refers to "bar" is not relevant; that's just not how JavaScript works. The only thing that matters is how the function is invoked, not *where* it's invoked, in other words.

If "bar.foo" looked like this:

```
bar.foo = function() { require("./foo"); foo.call(this); }
```

then you'd see "bar" in the console. Or, you could do this:

```
var bar = {};
require("./foo");
bar.foo = foo;
```

Then calling `bar.foo()` would also log the "bar" object. (Does that really work in Node?  That is, I thought `require()` returned an object, and that it didn't just leave things in the global scope. I'm a rank novice at Node however.)

*edit* — OK thanks for updating.  Thus, my example would be corrected as follows.  First, I think that your module should look like this:

```
(function() {
   var logThis = function() { console.log(this); }
   module.exports.logThis = logThis;
}).call(this);
```

That is, I think that you want to explort the "logThis" function, so it needs to be bound to the "exports" object as a named property.

Then:

```
var bar = {};
var foo = require("./foo");
// At this point, foo.logThis is the function 
bar.foo = foo.logThis;
// Now the "foo" property of "bar" is a reference to the same function
bar.foo(); // logs the "bar" object

var fee = { fie: foo.logThis };
fee.fie(); // logs the "fee" object
```

Comment: You can say: `bar.foo = require("./foo");` And you're right, I was invoking `foo()` with the wrong `this`. However, this still doesn't answer my question since when I changed the module to use `(function() { ... })();` instead of `(function() { ... }).call(this)`, I still see the "bar" object when I call `bar.foo();`. In this case I really did expect to see the global object. So I'm still not clear on what difference the two constructs make in this context.

Comment: Oh and you're right, my code sample contained a typo. I corrected it so that the value returned by `require()` is assigned to a variable `foo` as it should be.

Comment: Updated the question to explain why this doesn't completely answer it.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. You're absolutely right except for two things: (1) in Node.js you would generally say `exports.logThis = ...` to bind a value to the `logThis` property, but I can also say `module.exports = ...` so that the module itself is bound to that property. So it is correct to use it in the way I did in my original question. (2) I still get the same behavior (which you correctly describe) if I use `(function() { ... })()` in my module instead of `(function() { ... }).call(this)`. So I'm still in the dark as to why `call(this)` is used, which was the thrust of my original question.

Comment: @MatthewGertner Well as is probably clear by now I'm certainly not an expert at this module business :-)  My strong suspicion, however, is that the `.call(this)` to allow a module definition to be evaluated in a context where `this` is *not* the global object, so that you could achieve a "local" import without affecting the global namespace.

Comment: @MatthewGertner also, consider that by using `.call(this)` it'd be possible to compose different sub-modules together so that their exports are all part of a single combined object.

Comment: `.call(this)` won't help in composing modules since new symbols go into `exports` and not into `this`.At this point I'm assuming that `.call(this)` is either a hypercorrect form that isn't really necessary for modules like Underscore or that it's for a use case that isn't Node.js or web and that hasn't occurred to me. Anyway, it's an interesting discussion and I'll accept your answer unless someone swoops in over the next couple of days with a concrete example where something like Underscore would act differently if the outer enclosure were invoked with `fn()` instead of `fn.call(this)`.

Comment: Ah, right; that makes sense.  I agree that it's interesting; "best practices" in modern JavaScript coding have been evolving so quickly over the past few years that it's hard to separate the wheat from the chaff sometimes :-)